# stopping jquery animation when not hovering

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted a question earlier about a `div` animation and I'm trying to modify it a bit. I have a `div` that rotates when the page loads. When hovering over it, I'd like for it to stop.

Here's the script

```
rotate(); //the function which rotates the div 
$("#div2").hover(function() {
    $("#div2").stop();
});​
```

Here's my JS page

```
var obj = "div2";
var angle = 0;
var interval = 2323;
increment = 5;

function rotate() {
    $('#' + obj).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
    angle += increment;
    setTimeout(rotate, interval);
}​
```

Comment: Do I really need to explicitly state that it won't stop when hovering?

Comment: Yes, you do, along with any other details that will help us help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `clearTimeout()` method. As an example:

```
var obj = "div2";
var angle = 0;
var interval = 100;
var increment = 5;
var timer = null;

function rotate() {
    $('#' + obj).css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
    angle += increment;
    timer = setTimeout(rotate, interval);
}

$("#div2").hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}, function() {
    rotate();
});

rotate(); //the function which rotates the div​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Uf9qZ/

Comment: I was going to propose a global boolean that would be checked inside the `rotate()` function and toggle with the `hover`, but your solution is much more elegant. +1 to you sir.

Comment: Doesn't work quite right. It doesn't rotate when the page loads, but when I mouse over and then back out it rotates slightly (5º maybe).

Comment: @user1104854 It has 5% angle increment in 2.3 sec. Try to decrease time increment. Check the DEMO in the answer update.

Comment: You're right, sorry I was a bit rushed on that. I can't believe I didn't notice the time. Is there any way to gradually slow the animation down rather than stopping it immediately?

Comment: @user1104854 Oh, that's an absolutely different story :) Possibly you have to use another `timeout` to increase the interval and finally clear all `timeouts`, but it will be heavy.

Answer (score 3):

```
var elm = $("#div2"),
    angle = 0,
    interval = 2323,
    increment = 5,
    T = setInterval(rotate, interval);

elm.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        clearInterval(T);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        T = setInterval(rotate, interval);
    }
});

function rotate() {
    elm.css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        'msTransform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)'
    });
    angle += increment;
}​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9ETt/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this one works too.  Is there any way to slowly bring "down" setinteral and then stop it? Say from 1 to 2000 and then stop?

Answer (score 1):

you are doing your own implementation of rotation, you will have to handle the management yourself as well, so cache the `setTimeout` object and use `clearTimeout` when you need to stop it